# Number of steps to find the number of primes less than or equal to $x$.

Tags: number-theory, functions, prime-numbers, asymptotics

Denote by $\pi(x)$ the number of primes less than or equal to $x$ (the prime counting function). I am curious how many steps it takes to find $\pi(x)$, where a step is defined is an elementary arithmetic operation. I know that the Lagarias-Odlyzko algorithm finds $\pi(x)$ in $O(x^{\frac{1}{2}+\epsilon})$ steps. Are there any better algorithms? How many steps do they take?

Comment: In 2016, Tim Trudgian proved an explicit upper bound for the difference between 
$\pi (x)$ and 
$\operatorname {li} (x)$: $$\big| \pi(x) - \operatorname{li}(x) \big| \le 0.2795 \frac{x}{(\ln x)^{3/4}}
\exp \left( -\sqrt{ \frac{\ln x}{6.455} } \right)$$ for all $x\ge229.$

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, that remains the best, though in practice the $O(x^{2/3}\log^{-x})$ and $O(x^{2/3}\log^{-2x})$ methods are faster.  See [Staple 2015](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1503.01839.pdf) and [primecount](https://github.com/kimwalisch/primecount).  Both with substantial influence from Gourdon 2001.  Staple notes the $O(x^{1/2+\epsilon})$ analytic methods have large implied constants.

Comment: @vitamind The author wants to determine $\pi(x)$ exactly.